# A calculation from opacity to grey?

Tags: html, css

Grey is simply black with a white background and a given opacity, if you choose to to express it this way. Can anyone express this quantitatively?

Comment: What is the purpose of this?

Comment: This question's a little too light on details and what you need. Please elaborate.

Comment: This question is quite clear!  There is nothing wrong with it.

Comment: I have troubles understanding what you exactly want to know. But basically grey is 50% of white or of brightness, depends on the color model that you use to express your colors... I'm really confused because you tagged this as CSS... Curious to hear more details !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose we have an element on a white `#ffffff` background.  If that element's RGBA values are `#000000ff`, the calculated color is `#000000`.  Along those same lines, `#00000000` makes the element effectively invisible, so the calculated color is `#ffffff`, the color of the background.

Since you are looking at grey, it is aligned perfectly.

- `#000000ff` = `#000000`
- `#000000ee` = `#111111`
- `#000000dd` = `#222222`
- etc.